# How to group by ID, and output without repeating IDs?

Tags: sql, excel

Input

```
UserID  Profile
101     apple
102     banana
103     pie
101     banana
102     pine
103     berry
```

Output

```
UserID  Profile
101     apple
        banana
102     banana
        pine
103     pie
        berry
```

Comment: Welcome to DS StackExchange. Please elaborate more on your questions. Show us the code you tried and what kind of errors you get. In this way the community will be able to help you

Answer (score 1):

This problem will by solved by group by function.

Whatever tool you are using (R or SQL), you need to just group the data by UserID.